# Google test - before class

Tags: c++, unit-testing, googletest

I'm running google test.

I need something like Before class. I have the `SetUp()` and `TearDown()` functions, but they run before and after **each** test. Now I need something global - like `ctor`, that should run only one time when the class loaded.

Comment: Please elaborate on this "one time when the class is loaded". What class are you referring to, and what does class "loading" mean?

Comment: I mean something that run before **all** tests start. not setup for each test case.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can define static member functions `void SetUpTestCase()` and `void TearDownTestCase()` in each of your fixture classes, i.e. in each class derived from `::testing::Test`.

That code will run only once for each fixture, before and after all test in the fixture are run.

Check the [docs](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/docs/advanced.md#sharing-resources-between-tests-in-the-same-test-case).

Comment: Perez - How can I do it for all the tests (in all test cases) ? I mean that I wish that before each test the same SetUp method will run as well as that after each test the same TearDown method will run, without adding/editing any existing class ?

Comment: @GuyAvraham: AFAIK there is no such hook function in the framework that allows you to do this. You'd need to build it yourself by maybe defining a child class for `::testing::Test` and then making your test classes derive from it instead.

Comment: Please note that in newer versions of gtest you might need to use `SetUpTestSuite()` and `TearDownTestSuite()` methods instead.

Comment: if you want global first-time initialization, just can use a static mutex and static bool to init for the only first time. But not sure for last-time global teardown.

Answer (score 13):

Inherit from class `::testing::Environment` and override methods `SetUp` and `TearDown`, these methods will contain code for your global setup and tear down. Then, in the main function of executable that runs you tests, call function `::testing::AddGlobalTestEnvironment()` before calling `RUN_ALL_TESTS()`. For more information, check the documentation:

https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/docs/advanced.md#global-set-up-and-tear-down

Comment: Page has moved -> https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/docs/advanced.md#global-set-up-and-tear-down